# Zend Framework - Form Element - Remove ID

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to remove the 'id' attribute that Zend Framework adds to every Form Element by default?

I've looked at the documentation but don't seem to be able to find an answer to this rather straight forward question.

### Possible Solution

Is there any cleaner way to do it other than setOption?

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$submit->setRequired(FALSE)
       ->setIgnore(TRUE)
       ->setDecorators($this->elementDecorators)
       ->setOptions(array('id' => ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to **override `Zend_View_Helper_Form` with your own View Helper**. 
But sincerely, don't take too much attention to this id attribute in your form, you will sooner or later need this id (if you're using Javascript for example) and the performance gain (to render the page) is too tiny to be taken into consideration. It will even be a performance loss since you're going to override a Helper.

If your purpose is different and you want to do that anyway, you need to write you own View Helper as follow:

```
class My_View_Helper_Form extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement
{
    public function form($name, $attribs = null, $content = false)
    {
        $info = $this->_getInfo($name, $content, $attribs);
        extract($info);


        $xhtml = '<form'
               . $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs)
               . '>';

        if (false !== $content) {
            $xhtml .= $content
                   .  '</form>';
        }

        return $xhtml;
    }
}
```

Finally, you simply need to overload the default view helper using a plugin loader. [Read the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.pluginloader.html#zend.loader.pluginloader.usage) for more information about plugin loader.